# Python replace to get rid of white space not working

Tags: python, replace

I'm trying to get rid of spaces in a string using python's replace(), but it doesn't seem to be working. Looking at past questions, most people have the issue of not catching the new string that is returned by the function, but I'm doing that. I'm not sure what else could be wrong.

My code looks like:

```
teamname = "University of Alabama"
teamname = teamname.replace(' ','')
print teamname
```

This should return "UniversityofAlabama", but instead it gives "University of Alabama" right back to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot duplicate. Post actual data and code.

Comment: copy and paste what you have there into a console ... at a guess you are getting html or something and spaces are not spaces .... but we cant tell you for sure because your code works fine here

Comment: In particular, there are a lot of things that _look_ like plain old spaces, but aren't. For example, try this: `teamname = u"University\u00a0of\u00a0Alabama"`. If you `print(teamname)`, it looks identical to what you have. If you `print(repr(teamname))` you'll see the difference—which will also explain why `replace(' ', '')` doesn't work on it.

Comment: Also, according to Neil Young there is no space near Alabama. According to Lynyrd Skynyrd the skies are so blue that I imagine they can easily be mistaken for empty space, but you should always trust Neil Young over Lynyrd Skynyrd when it comes to Unicode.

Comment: I am grabbing the name from a url using Beautiful Soup, so I bet you're right that the spaces aren't actually spaces. How can I confirm? Copy/pasting what was printed to screen just gives regular spaces.

Comment: Just add `print repr(teamname)` right before the replace line.

Comment: Edit: Just saw the repr() hint. The output is indeed 'University\xc2\xa0of\xc2\xa0Alabama'. Thanks for pointing that out! I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Split it into a list then join it back together.

```
teamname = "University of Alabama"
teamname = teamname.split()
print teamname.join()
```